# passing non id parameter and returning individual object from $resource

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using $resource to return an array of objects.  Here is the method I am calling :

```
getTeamResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<ITeamResource> {
            return this.$resource("/api/Teams:teamId");
        }
```

And here is how I am calling it:

```
teamResource.query((data: app.domain.Team[]) => {
                this.scope.teams = data;
            });
```

This works perfectly, but now instead of returning an array, I want to pass in a parameter and return an individual object.  The object I want to return of of type app.domain.Team, and the parameter I want to pass is teamName rather than teamId.

The backend api that I want to call has the following signature :

```
// GET: api/Teams/Chicago Bears
        [HttpGet("api/Teams/{teamName}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTeamByName([FromRoute] string teamName)
        {....}
```

Hopefully this is an easy question, I am just trying to get to grips with the syntax required for $resource, so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does you backend expect a team name or id?  I assume that it is an id to find the team and not a name.

You can call $resource for get like so.

```
$resource.('/api/teams/:id', {id:'@id'}).get({id:1});
```

Comment: Nope, the backend in this case expects the team name not the id